# React : How to pass Authorization Access Token from Laravel passport to React component?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, access-token

I need to convert a `Laravel` `Edit Profile` form page to `React` (Partially), I am using `react-hook-form` for the `Edit Profile` page `form`, the `form` has an onsubmit `ajax call` ( POST `api/v1/user/profile/edit` ) that needs to be authorized with the `authorization header` with `access token`, the access token is generated by `Laravel Passport` like:

```
    public function login( LoginRequest $request )
    {
        // Parameter(s)
        $data = [
            'email'             => $request->email,
            'password'          => $request->password,
        ];

        // Login & Return User Model
        $user = $this->users->login( $data );

        // Create + Get Access Token
        $access_token = $user->createToken('user_access_token', [])
            ->accessToken;

        // Transform Result
        $result = $this->loginTransformer->transform( $user );

        // RETURN Result
        return $this->sendResponse($result, trans('api.user.login_success'))
            ->header('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$access_token);
```

How do I pass the `Laravel Passport` `access token` from `Laravel` to the frontend `React component`?

Comment: your question should be edited. if you're asking a React question you don't need to mention Laravel code. if you have a question about Laravel then you should remove React tag and name or ask it in another question separately.
but if I understood correctly: you should send AccessToken through the body of the login request in the Laravel and then when you got it in the front-end, you should add AccessToken in header of all request in Bearer structure.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I am confused and need to know how the flow works, For the login of the website, I am using the Laravel 'web,auth' middleware, instead of `auth:api`, do I need to convert all the frontend to backend request to use API instead?

Comment: then. it is better we go forward step by step. first of all, we should check and fix your backend. does your backend communicate with RESTful APIs?

Comment: my Laravel backend mostly communicate with the `web.auth` middleware instead of `auth:api`, so most of it use CSRF/session, should all the backend-to-frontend communication be switched to stateless `API` communication instead?

Comment: I don't know Laravel a lot, but if your auth scenario isn't using APIs but instead using session, then you can use cookies in front-end. but I think it is better to deal with APIs

Comment: I see, so if I use `API` for the `/login` request and after login success and it returned the `access token` to the frontend, how should I store it for later use? and how to use it for subsequent API request?